# How to fix the position of Google's +1 object near to another one on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, layout, position

I would like to place the +1 button on the bottom-left of a flash movie that will be on screen, leaving it right below a facebook button.

My site is http://www.quickguitartuner.com/ (if it refuse to load on the first attempt press F5. That's another problem I'm stuck in. If you know how to solve it, please tell me)

The page's code:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Quick Guitar Tuner</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<p align="center">
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="900" height="550">
    <param name="movie" value="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="900" height="550" quality="High">
    <div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=127418320673531&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.quickguitartuner.com/" send="true" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="" style="position:relative; left:600px; top:-300px"></fb:like>
    </object>
</p>
<p align="center">
    <g:plusone size="tall" href="www.quickguitartuner.com"></g:plusone>
</p>


<p align="center">0.4</p>


</body>

</html>
```

How can I do it?

## UPDATE

I did it by simply changing

```
<p align="center">
        <g:plusone size="tall" href="www.quickguitartuner.com"></g:plusone>
    </p>
```

for

```
<p align="center" style="position:relative; left:400px; top:-300px">
    <g:plusone size="tall" href="www.quickguitartuner.com"></g:plusone>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my answer too... (Deserves another best answer? rite?)

---

> Your update is not a workaround since
>   you are not using CSS and yes That is
>   the answer! What you did was, that you
>   put the alignment on the P tag so the
>   browser automatically renders the P
>   tag in the centre. But you can do this
>   as it will probably help you since it
>   is not safe to put the facebook inside
>   the swf object tag. this would be
>   better:

```
<p align="center"><u>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000" id="obj1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" border="0" width="900" height="550">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.quickguitartuner.com/Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="Flash/bin/main2_secure.swf" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="obj1" width="900" height="550" quality="High">
</object>
</u></p>
    <p align="center"><div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=127418320673531&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.quickguitartuner.com/" send="true" layout="box_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="" ></fb:like>
</p>
```